# windows custom authentication using custom credential providers

Tags: authentication, com, windows-10, credentials, credential-providers

I want to launch a standalone application which i developed using mean stack when windows boot. I wanted to use this application to do some bio-metric authentication and login windows using WINDOWS CUSTOM CREDENTIAL.

I found sample credential provider in Microsoft forum https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/V2-Credential-Provider-7549a730#content  but I'm new and not sure how to customize this code to launch my application.

Can someone please share me some clear guide or help me to launch this application?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

To make the credential provider launch on startup you need to add it to the registry.

**Steps**

1. Copy the DLL, which you have build (be sure that if you have a 64 bit machine you also build the DLL for it!) to the /Windows/System32
2. Go to REGEDIT (WindowsKey + R > regedit)
3. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Authentication/Credential Providers
4. Add a new key with a unique id, and the name of you dll **without** ".dll"
5. That's it, to enable the credential provider.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A7FA450-1F33-41F7-9E6D-3AA95B5A6AEA/MSDNMagazineJanuary2007en-us.chm < that's some documentation go to the tab: "Create Custom Login Experiences With Credential Providers For Windows Vista"